# Issue with xscale and bar width

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js

I have a bar graph with initial width set. say w= 500.
The initial length of data may vary from 1 to n.
[Full length data](http://jsfiddle.net/oc81djhe/)
In case if data.length =1 The width of the bar is too large [too large](http://jsfiddle.net/oc81djhe/) as shown here.

I did try to reduce the size by increasing and decreasing the width by setting the width like

```
 var w = 50* dataset.length;
  //Create X Scale for bar graph
   var xScale = d3.scale.ordinal().domain(input.map(function (d) {
    return d.AppName;
  })).rangeRoundBands([0, w], 0.05);
```

[xscale too short with rigth bar width](http://jsfiddle.net/pezr4d7v/)
The bar width Issue seems to be resolved but I see that x-axis is too short and looks awkward. How to fix this issue?

[image: Required Xaxis Image attached]

Comment: "The bar width Issue seems to be resolved but I see that x-axis is too short and looks awkward". Can you explain how you want the x-axis look to look in the case there there is just one value in the data?

Comment: Have edited the post to reflect the required xaxis length even when I have a dataset with an array[0].

Comment: Take a look at the answers to this similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/13760253/3442309